# EmberJS loading child records

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am trying to load a list of responses for a post (a post hasMany responses). It does not feel right because I do not have routes or controllers for responses(I create responses via a function in posts_show controller). I intend to load the list of responses for a post in `posts.show`.

Router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new')
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:post_id/edit' })
    this.route('show', { path: '/:post_id' })
}),
this.resource('users', function() {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:user_id' })
})


});
```

So in my posts.show route, I want to show a list of all responses for that post because a post hasMany responses and a response belongsTo a post:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
 title: DS.attr('string'),
 post_content: DS.attr('string'),
 author: DS.attr('string'),
 responses: DS.hasMany('App.Response'),
 updated_at: DS.attr('date'),
 announcement: DS.attr('boolean')

});

App.Response = DS.Model.extend({
 response_content: DS.attr('string'),
 response_author: DS.attr('string'),
 post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
})
```

My posts.show template has the following:

```
{{#each responses}}
```

To access the responses of that post. Is this the right way? I feel it isn't because I am creating a response in the controller for a post.

Answer (score 1):

In your posts handlebars template you would do something like this

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  {{#each response in post.responses}}
    {{response.response_content}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Just make sure the controller for the template above is an ArrayController